# How do I get information from build method into render array and rendered?

Tags: blocks, hooks

I have a region that I need to sometimes render differently, based on a value  in the build method. The build array has the correct information, but by the time it gets the preprocessor its gone and is not rendered.

```
class ProfileHeader extends BlockBase {
     public function build(): array {
      if ($somethingspecific) {
      $build['content_name'][] = $this->getMobileBlock();
       }
      return $build;
    }
}
```

Where

```
  protected function getMobileBlock($X) {
    $info = X::getInfo();
    if ($info) {
      $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('info');
      return $view_builder->view($info, 'profile_heading_small');;
    }
    return NULL;
  }
```

In my template preprocessor

```
function template_preprocess_header(&$variables) {
   // If I debug here, I wont see my information in the variables and wont be rendered
}
```

In my block preprocessor

```
function MODULE_preprocess_block($variables) {
   // If I debug here, I can see the information, but its not rendered
}
```

Comment: The theme/template for a block is named `block`, so the preprocess would be `MODULE_preprocess_block`

Comment: Thanks, I updated